# PostgreSQL Multi master Synchronisation

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

I have a scenario as follows,

1. One cloud server is running an application with PGSQL as DB
2. Multiple local servers are running with same application with PGSQL as DB
3. User may access the cloud server for read/write data
4. User may access any of the local server to read/write data

What I need is synchronisation between all these databases. The synchronisation can be done live if connectivity is available, or immediately when connectivity is available.

Please guide me with some inputs, where can i start from.

Answer (score 0):

Rethink your requirements.

Multimaster replication is full of pitfalls, and it is easy to get your databases out of sync unless you plan carefully. You'd probably be better off with a single master node.

That said, you could look at BDR by 2ndQuadrant which provides such functionality.